# How to add a drop down with option groups and option values?

Tags: profile

I planning to add a drop down button with option groups and option values.

This is my code

```
$form->add('select', 'a', ts('a'),
            array(
              '1' => ts('value 1'),
              '2' => ts('value 2')
              ) 
            );
```

Is there any efficient method to do it? Also i want to capture the option value and save it to a variable in order to save it in the database. I have tried `$form->getvalue('a')`, but didn't work. Much appreciate if someone could help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a setting for your extension, then take a look at the settings framework: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/setting/#creating-a-new-setting-in-an-extension

If you're modifying a form, then you can get the value when the person submits the form using hook_postProcess: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_postProcess. One way it to use `$form->_submitValues` which is an array.